# Mysql optimization help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have a table TABLE_A with 4397898 records

`+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| usrid             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| grpid             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| catid             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| folderid          | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | 5       |                |
| popid             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| accid             | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| contentid         | bigint(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| priority          | smallint(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rating            | smallint(6)   | NO   |     | 3       |                |
| fromid            | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ctxid             | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ctxmsgid          | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| starred           | enum('Y','N') | YES  |     | N       |                |
| links             | enum('y','n') | YES  |     | n       |                |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

and it is indexed as below

`+---------+----+--------------+-----+-------------+-----+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
| Table   | Nu | Key_name     | Seq | Column_name | Col | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | 
+---------+----+--------------+-----+-------------+-----+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
| TABLE_A |  0 | PRIMARY      |   1 | id          | A   |     4617132 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| TABLE_A |  1 | catIndx      |   1 | catid       | A   |      256507 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| TABLE_A |  1 | contentIndx  |   1 | contentid   | A   |     4617132 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| TABLE_A |  1 | catIndx_2    |   1 | catid       | A   |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| TABLE_A |  1 | catIndx_2    |   2 | popid       | A   |        2013 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| TABLE_A |  1 | folderidIndx |   1 | folderid    | A   |       13619 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| TABLE_A |  1 | accIndex     |   1 | accid       | A   |        1532 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| TABLE_A |  1 | popindx      |   1 | popid       | A   |        1532 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
+---------+----+--------------+-----+-------------+-----+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+`

The following query

<s>`explain SELECT
intCommIndx 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ( 
(popid IN('-1',2407 ,22 ,1203   ,1342   ,1207   ,3  ,1254   ,2663   ,1250   ,3461   ,1251   ,14 ,1174   ,120    ,2406   ,2402   ,325    ,925    ,1210   ,2280   ,1  ,1202   ,1560   ,775    ,776    ,789    ,777    ,778    ,12 ,779    ,780    ,781    ,782    ,783    ,784    ,785    ,786    ,787    ,788    ,1209   ,19 ,26 ,9  ,24 ,4  ,25 ,21 ,18 ,1309   ,967    ,1212   ,6  ,9633   ,5  ,2671   ,17 ,13 ,1211   ,749    ,752    ,747    ,750    ,748    ,9302   ,1470   ,190    ,188    ,9711   ,9710   ,9512   ,11512  ,9514   ,9515   ,9516   ,11511  ,9513   ,9316   ,9453   ,1641   ,4986   ,1639   ,1640   ,7814   ,10042  ,9452   ,11236  ,11241  ,11238  ,11239  ,11237  ,11242  ,11240  ,1711   ) OR intpop3indx = -1) 
AND catid = 5 )`</s>

`explain SELECT
id
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ( 
(popid IN('-1',2407 ,22 ,1203   ,1342   ,1207   ,3  ,1254   ,2663   ,1250   ,3461   ,1251   ,14 ,1174   ,120    ,2406   ,2402   ,325    ,925    ,1210   ,2280   ,1  ,1202   ,1560   ,775    ,776    ,789    ,777    ,778    ,12 ,779    ,780    ,781    ,782    ,783    ,784    ,785    ,786    ,787    ,788    ,1209   ,19 ,26 ,9  ,24 ,4  ,25 ,21 ,18 ,1309   ,967    ,1212   ,6  ,9633   ,5  ,2671   ,17 ,13 ,1211   ,749    ,752    ,747    ,750    ,748    ,9302   ,1470   ,190    ,188    ,9711   ,9710   ,9512   ,11512  ,9514   ,9515   ,9516   ,11511  ,9513   ,9316   ,9453   ,1641   ,4986   ,1639   ,1640   ,7814   ,10042  ,9452   ,11236  ,11241  ,11238  ,11239  ,11237  ,11242  ,11240  ,1711   ) OR popid = -1) 
AND catid = 5 )`

gives

`+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys             | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLE_A | ref  | catIndx,catIndx_2,popindx | catIndx | 5       | const | 649800 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+`

How to improve the speed of the query?

There are only 850 rows in the result.

`mysql> SELECT 
    -> count(id) 
    -> FROM TABLE_A
    -> WHERE ( 
    -> (popid IN('-1',2407,22,1203,1342,1207,3,1254,2663,1250,3461,1251,14,1174,120,2406,2402,325,925,1210,2280,1,1202,1560,775,776,789,777,778,12,779,780,781,782,783,784,785,786,787,788,1209,19,26,9,24,4,25,21,18,1309,967,1212,6,9633,5,2671,17,13,1211,749,752,747,750,748,9302,1470,190,188,9711,9710,9512,11512,9514,9515,9516,11511,9513,9316,9453,1641,4986,1639,1640,7814,10042,9452,11236,11241,11238,11239,11237,11242,11240,1711) OR intpop3indx = -1) 
    -> AND catid = 5 );
+--------------------+
| count(id) |
+--------------------+
|                850 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (11.22 sec)`

What changes can I make to get these 850 records within milliseconds?

Comment: Regardless of your query shape, you are asking mysql to return 649800 records. It is unusual, from the user ergonomy perspective. Maybe you want to refine this request?

Answer (score 1):

This is the query:

```
SELECT intCommIndx 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE ( (popid IN('-1',2407 ,22 ,1203   ,1342   ,1207   ,3  ,1254   ,2663   ,1250   ,3461   ,1251   ,14 ,1174   ,120    ,2406   ,2402   ,325    ,925    ,1210   ,2280   ,1  ,1202   ,1560   ,775    ,776    ,789    ,777    ,778    ,12 ,779    ,780    ,781    ,782    ,783    ,784    ,785    ,786    ,787    ,788    ,1209   ,19 ,26 ,9  ,24 ,4  ,25 ,21 ,18 ,1309   ,967    ,1212   ,6  ,9633   ,5  ,2671   ,17 ,13 ,1211   ,749    ,752    ,747    ,750    ,748    ,9302   ,1470   ,190    ,188    ,9711   ,9710   ,9512   ,11512  ,9514   ,9515   ,9516   ,11511  ,9513   ,9316   ,9453   ,1641   ,4986   ,1639   ,1640   ,7814   ,10042  ,9452   ,11236  ,11241  ,11238  ,11239  ,11237  ,11242  ,11240  ,1711   ) OR intpop3indx = -1
        ) AND
        catid = 5
       )
```

Queries with `or` can be quite hard to optimize.  I would recommend creating two indexes on the table and then rewriting the query.  The two indexes are `intCommIndx(catid, popid, intCommIndx)` and `intCommIndx(catid, intpop3indx, intCommIndx)`.  Then the new query is:

```
SELECT intCommIndx 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE catid = 5 and
      popid IN ('-1',2407 ,22 ,1203   ,1342   ,1207   ,3  ,1254   ,2663   ,1250   ,3461   ,1251   ,14 ,1174   ,120    ,2406   ,2402   ,325    ,925    ,1210   ,2280   ,1  ,1202   ,1560   ,775    ,776    ,789    ,777    ,778    ,12 ,779    ,780    ,781    ,782    ,783    ,784    ,785    ,786    ,787    ,788    ,1209   ,19 ,26 ,9  ,24 ,4  ,25 ,21 ,18 ,1309   ,967    ,1212   ,6  ,9633   ,5  ,2671   ,17 ,13 ,1211   ,749    ,752    ,747    ,750    ,748    ,9302   ,1470   ,190    ,188    ,9711   ,9710   ,9512   ,11512  ,9514   ,9515   ,9516   ,11511  ,9513   ,9316   ,9453   ,1641   ,4986   ,1639   ,1640   ,7814   ,10042  ,9452   ,11236  ,11241  ,11238  ,11239  ,11237  ,11242  ,11240  ,1711   )
UNION
SELECT intCommIndx 
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE catid = 5 and intpop3indx = -1;
```

This will allow each subquery to be satisfied only using the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put the last conditions in first position. So when one of them isn't verified, we pass directly to the other row :

```
catid = 5 AND (intpop3indx = -1 OR popid IN (...))
```

So when `catid != 5`, the query passes directly to the other row. (Even if `catid = 5 AND intpop3indx = -1`)

Comment: But maybe your indexes are not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is selecting column `intCommIndx` from the table, but that column does not appear as one of the table columns.

The quick answer is to create a "covering index" e.g.

```
... ON TABLE_A (catid, intpop3indx, popid, intCommIndx)
```

`EXPLAIN` output should show "Using index" in the Extra column, which means the query is satisfied entirely from the index without a need to look up pages from the table.